# "Unrecognizable signature" error when marshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I have the following code:

```
    javax.xml.bind.Marshaller m = ...
    java.io.OutputStream outputStream = ...
    Object jaxbElement = ...
    m.marshal(jaxbElement, outputStream);
```

It works fine.

I also have the following code:

```
    javax.xml.bind.Marshaller m = ...
    java.io.BufferedWriter writer = ...
    Object jaxbElement = ...
    m.marshal(jaxbElement, writer);
```

Executing the call to marshal in this case gives the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.IOException: Unrecognizable signature: "<?xml version="1.0" e".]
```

**jaxbElement in both cases is the same.**

Why would the first example work, while the second example fails?

Comment: should the first (working) example read:  `m.marshal(jaxbElement, outputStream);` rather than `m.marshal(jaxbElement, jaxbElement);`?

Comment: Could you expand your question?  Based on what you have posted I have not been able to reproduce the error you are seeing.  Also could you post your stack trace?

Comment: Yes, it should.  I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce the exception you are seeing, the following works for me.

**Foo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("Hello World");
        marshal(jc, foo);

        Object jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<Foo>(new QName("root"), Foo.class, foo);
        marshal(jc, jaxbElement);
    }

    private static void marshal(JAXBContext jc, Object jaxbElement) throws Exception {
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(stringWriter);
        m.marshal(jaxbElement, writer);
        writer.close();
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><foo><bar>Hello World</bar></foo>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><root><bar>Hello World</bar></root>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try working up from your example to my code and see where it starts going wrong.

Comment: @PaulReiners - What environment are you running your app in (SE, app server, OSGi, etc)?

Comment: @PaulReiners - If you are using JDK 1.6 or 1.7 then you don't need to add the JAXB public API to your class path (if you are currently doing so).  This could potentially cause some sort of signature mismatch.